# Difference between cosh and cos in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

So I have to solve this equation:

$$\cos z=0$$

Solution:

$$\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=0$$
$$e^{iz}+e^{-iz}=0$$
$$e^{i2z}=-1$$

Here I get stuck. The answer is obviously $\pi/2+k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ But I can't seem to figure what to do here to proove it but the thing that worries me more is that 
$$\cosh z=\cos z$$
but 
$$\cosh z \neq \cos z$$ 
$$\cosh z=i(k\pi+\pi/2), k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Why is that true, how two functions which look the same way can have different values ?!

How do I prove that $\cos z=\pi/2+k\pi$

Comment: $-1 = e^{i(2k+1)\pi}$ so $e^{2iz} = e^{i(2k+1)\pi} \Rightarrow 2iz = i(2k+1)\pi$. Also, I'm not sure why you think $\cosh z = \cos z$.

Comment: It should be $\cosh (z) = \cos (iz)$, but I don't see why it would help you solving that equation.

Comment: you cant solve $e^{i2z}=-1$ if you dont know previously that $e^{i\pi+i2\pi\Bbb Z}=-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand using 
$$
 \cos z = \cos \left( x + i y \right) = 
\cos x \cos (iy) - \sin x \sin (iy) =
\cos x \cosh y + i \sin x \sinh y
$$
Enforce
$$
\cos z = 0 + 0 i
$$

For the real part, the constraint is
$$
 \cos x  = 0 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad x = \frac{\pi}{2} + k \pi, \quad k\in\mathbb{Z}
$$

For the imaginary part, the constraint
$$
\sin x \sinh y = 0 
\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad
y = 0
$$

The solution to 
$$
\boxed{
\cos z = 0 
\qquad \Rightarrow \qquad
z = \left( \frac{\pi}{2} + k \pi \right) + 0i, \quad
}
$$